# Linux Kernel Module programming Makefile error

Tags: c, linux, module, compiler-errors, kernel

I am trying to compile a "Hello world" `linux kernel module` programming in `Fedora 14`.
My kernel version is "`2.6.35.14-97.fc14.i686`" which i am referring to `/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD)` modules in the make file to compile my `hello.o` program.

This "build" file showing it as special file and linked to source in `/lib/module/2.6....i686/` folder.

When i compile my code getting below error.

```
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.35.14-97.fc14.i686/build M=/root/kernel modules
make: *** /lib/modules/2.6.35.14-97.fc14.i686/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

My `Makefile` :

```
obj-m +=hello.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

Please give me solution to run this module program.

Comment: message is clear enough... there's no `build` directory, or at least one of the parent dirs (/lib, /lib/modules, /lib/modules/2.6...) is missing.

Comment: Check which /lib/modules/* directory you have. Probably not `2.6.35.14-97.fc14.i686`... For Ubuntu it is `3.5.0-22-generic`, don't know for Fedora.

Comment: Do you have kernel-devel or similar package in your system installed?

Comment: @Veger: Not really. It depends on the kernel version installed, not on the installed OS. Per example, I have a custom built 3.7 kernel on Ubuntu. `shell uname -r` should take the installed version, though.

Comment: @netcoder I know, but `2.6.35.14-97.fc14.i686` seemed a bit 'too much' detail in the version name. But again, I do not know how Fedora manages its versions...

Comment: Does the directory `/lib/modules/2.6.35.14-97.fc14.i686` exist? If so, does the symlink `/lib/modules/2.6.35.14-97.fc14.i686/build` exist? If it does, where does it point and does that target exist? (You likely need to install the `kernel-devel` (or whatever Fedora calls it) that corresponds to the kernel you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

You should only need 'kernel-devel' which you can install using yum for it. I use ubuntu and I just had to download the package 3.5.0-22-generic for it to work but a quick 'Kernal development module for Fedora' search on google led me [Here](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Core/6/html/Release_Notes/ar01s07s07.html)
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

compile your kernel and install the modules INSTALL_MOD_PATH=/path/
while compiling your hello world .link module path like 
MAKE -C KDIR=INSTALL_MOD_PATH M='$PWD' modules

Comment: Please try to explain your answer more. What does it do? Why does it solve the problem?

Comment: Xaver Kapeller by compiling modules will links certain module with linker. suppose your module uses netlink . enable netlink module before compiling .

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others please install "kernel-devel". This worked perfectly for me.

You can install it by:

```
yum install kernel-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the right version of kernel-devel ,you should append kernel version (**uname -r**) to the kernel-devel.

For example:
I executed  "**yum install kernel-devel-4.8.6-300.fc25.x86_64**" and it worked.